# Using SetParent freeze the parent window

Tags: c#, winapi, c#-4.0

I have an application in C# which creates a form and stack it in front of another app's window.
I do this by using `SetParent`. However, the (new) parent window freezes.

How can I solve that? Is this a matter of threading?

This is working:

```
private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormCover cov = new FormCover();
            IntPtr hwnd = Win32Utils.FindWindowByCaptionStart(IntPtr.Zero, TrackerName, null);

            Win32Utils.SetParent(cov.Handle, hwnd);
            cov.SetDesktopLocation(0, 0);

            cov.Show();
        }
```

But this (with a timer elapsed event) is **not**:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

FormCover cover;

void tmrCheck_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowCover();
        }

private void ShowCover()
        {
            cover = new FormCover();
            IntPtr hwnd = Win32Utils.FindWindowByCaptionStart(IntPtr.Zero, TrackerName, null);

            cover.CoverInitialize(hwnd);
            cover.Activate();
        }
}
//------

public partial class FormCover : Form
    {
        public delegate void IntPtrDlg(IntPtr param);

        public FormCover()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal void CoverInitialize(IntPtr hwdnParent)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new IntPtrDlg(CoverInitialize), new object[] { hwdnParent });
            }
            else
            {
                Win32Utils.SetParent(this.Handle, hwdnParent);
                this.SetDesktopLocation(0, 0);
            }
        }

        internal void CoverActivate(IntPtr handleFormulario)
        {
            if (!Visible)
                this.Show();
        }

        internal void CoverFinalize()
        {
            Hide();
            Win32ParentUtils.SetParent(Handle, new IntPtr());
        }
    }
```

What is the difference between these two samples? The first one is working fine, the second one is freezing the aprent window.

Comment: I guess you can't just create a window simply like this... A window needs a message pump, when it is no modal window.

Comment: Try to run the whole ShowCover method on the GUI thread(by using (Begin)Invoke method) as you do in CoverInitialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I just stated, you'll need to create a message pump for your form.
Try

```
Thread thread = new Thread( () =>
{
     var formCover = new FormCover();
     Application.Run(formCover);
});
thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
thread.Start();
```

Then you should be able to set the parent of your form.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3f0e7794-8671-47c4-aa9a-3bd1f85c9963) for further reference.

Comment: This worked perfectly. However, when I resize the parent window, the child window disappears. It does NOT happen when I move the parent window, or focus any of it child controls. It only is sent down the z-index when the window is resized. I guess I sould call BringToFront, but it is never called. I should start another question I guess.

Comment: The second question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979341/capture-resize-from-external-window-in-c-sharp