# MFC: Freezing on dialog SetParent()

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

Note: [Using SetParent freeze the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976155/using-setparent-freeze-the-parent-window) exists, but does NOT seem to be related to this problem as its in an entirely different framework, in a different language, and seems to be an issue with the message pump (though the message pump here could be the problem, I dont think any solution directly helps the problem I am facing here)

I am trying to create a dialog in MFC and attaching it to a parent window as a modeless dialog. My first attempt at this looks like the following:

```
    // Add window to the segment dialog vector
    m_segmentDialogs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<DlgSegmentDatum>(this));
    const int tab_number = m_segmentDialogs.size() - 1;

    std::string tab_text = "Segment " + std::to_string(tab_number);
    m_tabSegments.InsertItem(tab_number, tab_text.c_str());

    // Initialize the new dialog
    auto& dlg = m_segmentDialogs.back();
    dlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG_SEGMENT_DATUM, this);

    CRect rc_client, rc_window;
    m_tabSegments.GetClientRect(&rc_client);
    m_tabSegments.AdjustRect(FALSE, &rc_client);

    m_tabSegments.GetWindowRect(&rc_window);
    ScreenToClient(rc_window);

    rc_client.OffsetRect(rc_window.left, rc_window.top);

    dlg->MoveWindow(&rc_client);

    displaySegmentTab(tab_number);
```

This results in the child dialog spawning in the top left corner of the my screen. I assumed that this was because the child dialog didn't associate itself with the parent for some reason. To fix this, I updated the following code segment.

```
    // Initialize the new dialog
    auto& dlg = m_segmentDialogs.back();
    dlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG_SEGMENT_DATUM, this);
    dlg->SetParent(this);
```

This positions the dialog correctly, but immediately freezes the program.

Comment: I could be mistaken but it looks like `dlg->SetParent(this);` is setting `this` as its own parent since `this` was added to the `m_segmentDialogs` vector previously in the same block of code.

Comment: @DaveRager https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique. This was passed as a parameter to the constructor of the segment class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create Dialog resource, it has `WS_POPUP` style by default. To make it a child of another window, it has to be `WS_CHILD`.

You can either fix it in your resource file (easy), or, if you use that template elsewhere as a modal dialog, modify its style at run time using [ModifyStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#modifystyle)

Comment: I previously had tried this and had no success. I had something along the lines of 
dlg->ModifyStyles(WS_POPUP, WS_CHILD) when I was trying to fix this earlier. I checked my resoruce and the resource itself already had WS_CHILD set.

Comment: @Siech0 - please post the entire style line from your resource file. This works fine in my test app; the position of that second dialog changes from screen's (0,0) to client area when I change the style from `WS_POPUP` to `WS_CHILD`. I see that you are using some kind of "tabs" - may be that dialog should be a child of that tab?

Comment: The overall code looks a bit different now, but changing to use the tab control as parent seems to have helped. The positioning seems wrong still, but I think I have that fixed as well. Thanks.

Comment: Also make sure to set the `DS_CONTROL` or `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` styles appropriately. Otherwise keyboard navigation won't work as expected. See [What is the DS_CONTROL style for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040730-00/?p=38293) for details.